# Laravel Eloquent toSql() missing joined tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship that actually correctly returns joined values when I use `with("relationship")`. The problem is I suspect it is using a loop to get the values so I wanted to check the generated sql. The problem is that the SQL generated doesn't include the joined tables at all...

```
json_encode(User::find(1)->materials()->where("id", 1)->with("exerciseRecords")->get()->toArray());
```

Correctly gives:

```
"[{"id":8091,...,"exercise_records":[{"id":28,...,"updated_at":"2023-12-09T01:22:51.000000Z"}]}]"
```

But

```
> User::find(1)->materials()->where("id", 1)->with("exerciseRecords")->toSql();
```

Just gives

```
"select * from `materials` where `materials`.`user_id` = ? and `materials`.`user_id` is not null and `id` = ?"
```

Does that mean that I should interpret that is definitely *does* use a loop? Or that `toSql` can't be trusted?

Comment: because that doesn't generate a single query, but multiple ... `toSql` is showing you the query to get the parents  (the base query; the one being built) ... there is another query using those ids retrieved to get the related records ... and as stated in the answer below you can check the query log to see what is actually happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just confirm whether Laravel is using separate queries, you can use the database query `log`, this will return an array of all the queries that were executed, including those for the eager loaded relationships. You will see that after the initial query to fetch materials, there's another query to fetch `exerciseRecords` for the loaded materials.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
User::find(1)->materials()->where("id", 1)->with("exerciseRecords")->get();
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
return $queries;
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out what I was really looking for was HasManyThrough that allowed me to filter...